# Allow only one checkbox to be checked when the boxes are placed in specific cells a range

Tags: checkbox

Please help me. I need a simple script for Google Sheets to allow only one of 6 checkboxes to be checked at a time

```
   function onEdit(e) {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var range = e.range;
   var CHECKBOX_CELLS = ["H1:H6"];
   var checkboxIndex = CHECKBOX_CELLS.indexOf(range.getA1Notation());

   if (activeSheet.getName() !== "TRIAL" VcheckboxIndex > -1 && range.getValue() == true) 
   {
    var sheet = range.getSheet();

    for (var i=0; i<CHECKBOX_CELLS.length; i++) {
    if (i==checkboxIndex) continue;

    sheet.getRange(CHECKBOX_CELLS[i]).setValue(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, `checkboxIndex` equals -1; you have then to change `CHECKBOX_CELLS` as following

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var CHECKBOX_CELLS = ['H1','H2','H3','H4','H5','H6'];
  var checkboxIndex = CHECKBOX_CELLS.indexOf(range.getA1Notation());
  if (activeSheet.getName() !== "TRIAL" && range.getValue() == true) {
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    for (var i=0; i<CHECKBOX_CELLS.length; i++) {
      if (i!=checkboxIndex) sheet.getRange(CHECKBOX_CELLS[i]).setValue(false);
    }
  }
}
```

for the whole column, or partial column

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var begin = 1;             // change as necessary
  var end = s.getLastRow();  // change as necessary
  var col = 8;               // H
  var row = r.getRow();
  if (s.getName()=="TRIAL" &&  row>=begin && row<=end && r.getColumn()==col && r.getValue()) {
    var values = s.getRange(begin,col,end-begin+1,1).getValues()
    for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
      values[i][0]=false
    }
    values[row-begin][0]=true
    s.getRange(begin,col,end-begin+1,1).setValues(values)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks what if the column is H1:H that is the whole column. how will I handle it in Var CHECKBOX_CELLS

Comment: Mike, sorry I executed that code yet it was not working I do know why

Comment: have you given permissions? here is an examplehttps://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14wHUXMNTRQAxxsKN89gM1Rxw4qrmyOKVrhe8rEPmpBQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: for an entire column, just specify the column ...https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AK2P4ILxlqIPbeDxdX6v5uJWfU5Q58mw5tRXMgWUfXE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry Mike, what if I want to use specific sheet like "TRIAL". How will I handle that

Comment: Add `s.getName()=="TRIAL"` in the test, see my updated proposal.

Comment: Mike, thank you, it works. However I want to know, is there anyway we can make the execution of the script  faster. It looks slower

Comment: Take the second script with global values in an array, then delete in your sheet the non necessary rows, especially if you have define checkboxes until the end of the sheet, or define `var end` as a specific row, not the last one